# How to preload routes so that keep-alive containing the router-view can cache it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have one of my templates like this :

`<keep-alive>` 
    `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />` 
`</keep-alive>`

Whenever I visit a url it gets cached as expected. But is there a way to preload all of the routes when the page loads so that all of the routes are cached without manually visiting them first ?

Here is a screenshot of the vue.js dev tools extension.

1. When the page loads : 
   [image]
2. When I manually visit all the routes: 
   [image]

Comment: how does your `router.js` file look like? I think if you remove the [lazy loading component import](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#lazy-loading-routes), all components should be preloaded.

Comment: @wittgenstein None of the components are lazy loaded but that's not the issue. See when ever I visit `/chat/:roomID` a `Chat` component is loaded into the `router-view` with `roomID` passed as `props` which then renders chat room's messages. I want to simulate visiting all the routes so that they all are cached without having to manually visit the route.

Comment: So you want all components to be added to the user's DOM? You could create a list of all your components, loop through and open each path, but add the style display: none; until all components are rendered in the DOM. I can't estimate the side effects of this.